# Simple program gets wrong data with fscanf from all files

Tags: c, scanf

I have a simple code that just reads a file with a format like

```
0.000000 17.437500
1.000000 17.441406
2.000000 17.451172
3.000000 17.458984
4.000000 17.468750
5.000000 17.486328
```

and have to work with this data. My problem is that even just after scanning the data the array doesnt have the same numbers as the text file, instead has something like:

```
0.000000 0.000000
1.000000 0.480469
2.000000 0.000000
3.000000 0.482422
4.000000 0.000000
5.000000 0.486328
6.000000 0.000000
7.000000 0.490234
8.000000 0.000000
9.000000 0.498047
10.000000 0.000000
11.000000 0.507812
12.000000 0.000000
13.000000 0.515625
14.000000 0.000000
15.000000 0.527344
16.000000 0.000000
```

Which to me seems pretty weird, with all even numbers being always 0, I thought it could be a clue but still can't find the problem.

Here's my code, I have already been working with fscanf and after 2 days hunting for the source of error and looking at the internet I still could'nt find the problem.

```
#include <assert.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <fftw3.h>
#include <gsl/gsl_math.h>
#include <gsl/gsl_interp2d.h>
#include <gsl/gsl_spline2d.h>

const int   N=360; // How many pairs of values in the file
const int   DataFiles=6000;  // How many data files are we going to read     

double *irad;

int get_indexrad(int,int);

int main() {
int i, j, kii , kjj , index,t,t0;
double (*d_r)[N]= malloc(sizeof(d_r[0])*DataFiles);
FILE * conf;
FILE * op;
char file[100];
int jump=5;
// Initialization of the memory
irad =   (double *) calloc(DataFiles*N, sizeof(double));

t0=4500;
/* open the file for reading and read the data into an array */
for (t=0; t<DataFiles; t++){

    sprintf(file,"./interfase-%i.txt",t0+t*jump);

    conf=fopen(file,"r");
    if(conf == NULL){
        perror("Could not open input file");
        return -1;}

    for(kii=0;kii<N;kii++){
        index=get_indexrad(t,kii);
        fscanf(conf,"%i %lf", &j, &irad[index]);
    }
    fclose(conf);
}

// Writing the first read file in a new txt to see if it was properly read
sprintf(file,"./Data/irad_t0.txt");
op=fopen(file,"w");
if(op == NULL){
    perror("Could not create file");
    return -1;}
t=0;
for(i=0;i<N;i++){
    index=get_indexrad(t,i);
    fprintf(op,"%f %lf\n", ((double)i), irad[index]);
}
fclose(op);
}

int get_indexrad(int t,int theta){
int index3;

index3=t*N + theta;
return index3;
}
```

Comment: Can you please remove the lines of code not related to the question? We don't need to see all your file opening logic etc

Comment: we didn't see the code of `get_indexrad`. If that function returns an out-of-bounds index, that would explain a lot. And yes, a [mcve] would be nice.

Comment: You're using `%i` to scan the first column, but it appears to be floating point, too.

Comment: @SteveSummit you just found the issue: `scanf` only succeeds scanning the integer data and stops there... some strange things occur then alterning 0 and decimal part of the float to read??

Comment: the best way to avoid this is to enable `-Wall` (`-Wformat`) when compiling with gcc.

Comment: Always check the return value of `fscanf()`, it can fail (as it just demonstrated).

Comment: @SteveSumit it seems that you found it, I didnt realized on the input document being wrong

Comment: @fdzglln By following [@unwind](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46450042/simple-program-gets-wrong-data-with-fscanf-from-all-files#comment79856261_46450042) advice, you will uncover more problems more rapidly.

Comment: BTW: Good use of `sizeof(ref_type[0])` idiom in `double (*d_r)[N]= malloc(sizeof(d_r[0])*DataFiles);`.  Could have used that later as `irad =   calloc(DataFiles*N, sizeof *irad);`

Comment: for ease of readability and understanding: 1) consistently indent the code.  Indent after every opening brace.  unindent before every closing brace.  Suggest each indent level be 4 spaces.  2) insert an appropriate space inside parens, around C operators, after commas, after semicolons.  3)  follow the axiom: *only one statement per line and (at most) one variable declaration per statement.*

Comment: when calling any of the heap allocation functions: (calloc, malloc, realloc) 1) always check (!=NULL) the returned value to assure the operation was successful.  2) the returned type is `void*` which can be assigned to any pointer.  Casting just clutters the code, making it more difficult to understand, debug, etc. 3) variable names should indicate `content` or `usage` (or better, both).

Comment: the posted code contains several 'magic' numbers.  'magic' numbers are numbers with no basis. I.E. 5, 100, 360, 6000.  'magic' numbers make the code much more difficult to understand, debug, etc.  Suggest using `#define` statements or an `enum` statement to give those 'magic' numbers meaningful names, then use those meaningful names throughout the code.

Comment: this line: `double (*d_r)[N]= malloc(sizeof(d_r[0])*DataFiles);` is saying that `d_r[]` is an array of pointers to doubles and that there are `N` pointers.  In C, the valid index into an array is in the range of 0...(number of elements in array -1).  So setting the 'N' element results in undefined behavior as the 'N' element is one past the end of the array.  Also, none of those pointers have been initialized and the initial pointer to the array of pointers: `d_r` has not been initialized

Comment: this line: `fscanf(conf,"%i %lf", &j, &irad[index]);` seems to be setting pointers in the array of pointers: `irad[]`  And it is setting the variable `j`.  However, `j` is never used in the loop where it is being repeatedly set.  And how is some external file going to know where some pointer should be assigned to point,  If the code really wants to ignore every even numbered data item in the input file, then suggest using some some input format specifier that will consume leading white space and ignore the data